# Understanding default queue channel / capacity behavior

Tags: spring-integration

I'm having a strange issue with spring integration priority channel (or that's at least where I think things go wrong). I have the following flow:

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(fileReadingMessageSource,
                        c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                                             .taskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize))
                                             .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
                .channel("alphabetically")
                .bridge(s -> s.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
                .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
                .get();
```

And the priority channel with capacity 1'000:

```
@Bean
    public PriorityChannel alphabetically(@Value("${inbound.sort.queue-capacity}") int capacity) {
        return new PriorityChannel(capacity, Comparator.comparing(left -> ((File) left.getPayload()).getName()));
    }
```

I'm using this flow to read about 20'000 files from the input directory. Everything works fine but after around 2'000 files the flow stops working and it's not picking up any new files.

I thought that the default behavior of the queue channel is that when it reaches the capacity, it will simply wait for the capacity to be released and accept the next files that would be queued? But I might got it wrong... If it's not the case and there is some timeout for the files that would be picked up by the poller and wouldn't have enough space in the priority channel, what would be your suggestion to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some logging to see what's going on; this works fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56259801Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56259801Application.class, args);
    }

    private int i;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "foo" + i++, e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5_000)
                    .taskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))))
                .log()
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue(3))
                .bridge(b -> b.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
                .log()
                .get();
    }

}
```

and

```
2019-05-28 13:43:59.719  INFO 75315 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo0, headers={id=d87cba1d-dc6b-fdf4-56ed-61f08048851b, timestamp=1559065439718}]
2019-05-28 13:43:59.719  INFO 75315 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo0, headers={id=d87cba1d-dc6b-fdf4-56ed-61f08048851b, timestamp=1559065439718}]
2019-05-28 13:43:59.724  INFO 75315 --- [           main] com.example.So56259801Application        : Started So56259801Application in 0.832 seconds (JVM running for 1.242)
2019-05-28 13:44:04.719  INFO 75315 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo1, headers={id=8b7676e6-9bac-cdf0-4f4c-38513267b666, timestamp=1559065444719}]
2019-05-28 13:44:09.721  INFO 75315 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo2, headers={id=3b5346f8-d007-dd33-bee3-28eed4cfbd00, timestamp=1559065449721}]
2019-05-28 13:44:10.727  INFO 75315 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo1, headers={id=8b7676e6-9bac-cdf0-4f4c-38513267b666, timestamp=1559065444719}]
2019-05-28 13:44:10.727  INFO 75315 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo2, headers={id=3b5346f8-d007-dd33-bee3-28eed4cfbd00, timestamp=1559065449721}]
2019-05-28 13:44:14.723  INFO 75315 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo3, headers={id=84df8665-1aa9-df90-2037-4dd1781b1bf3, timestamp=1559065454723}]
2019-05-28 13:44:19.727  INFO 75315 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo4, headers={id=4e81897b-a19c-4789-529a-46266762ccc6, timestamp=1559065459727}]
2019-05-28 13:44:21.733  INFO 75315 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo3, headers={id=84df8665-1aa9-df90-2037-4dd1781b1bf3, timestamp=1559065454723}]
2019-05-28 13:44:21.733  INFO 75315 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo4, headers={id=4e81897b-a19c-4789-529a-46266762ccc6, timestamp=1559065459727}]
2019-05-28 13:44:24.730  INFO 75315 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=foo5, headers={id=3fb96f4a-7d25-f94a-23d2-d4a121932554, timestamp=1559065464730}]
```